# Move subdirectories up one level for folder names that have certain string

Tags: powershell

The folders structure is as follows:

```
-User1folder
---->User1upload
---------->Upload Subfolder
---->miscfolder

-User2folder
---->User2upload
---->othermisc folder
```

There are root user folders (e.g., User1folder,user2folder).

Under that main root folder there are miscellaneous folders, the important one is the folder that contains the text 'upload' in its name.How can I move any subfolders under the user folders that contain 'upload' up to the main user folder?

Example:

```
-User1Folder
---->Upload subfolder\Client1\Sub1
```

The script should move subfolders under the upload folder to the main root account so it looks like this

```
->User1Folder
---->Upload subfolder
---->Client1\Sub1\
```

Current code I am using which only moves files up a single level:

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path 'C:\inetpub\EFTRoot\NEIS Site\Usr\*\*upload*\' |
    ForEach-Object {
        Get-ChildItem -File -Path $_.FullName |
            ForEach-Object {
            $nextName = $_.FullName
            $num = 1
            while(Test-Path -Path $nextName)
            {
            $nextName = Join-Path  (Split-Path -Parent (Split-Path -Parent $_.FullName)) ($_.BaseName + "_$num" + $_.Extension)
            $num++
            }
                Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $nextName
                Move-Item -Destination { $_.Directory.Parent.FullName }
                $files | Remove-Item -Recurse
            }
    }
```

Comment: please share your code of what you have tried so far.

Comment: SO has rules: [Provide MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) --- [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) --- [Don't ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) --- [Proper Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) --- [Why not upload images of code/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) --- [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: I added an example of what I currently have in post

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. First I CD into the folder and run the following:

```
dir -Directory | % {Push-Location $_.FullName; dir './*upload*/*' | % {Move-Item $_.FullName .}; del './*upload*/*'; Pop-Location}
```

Found info here: https://superuser.com/questions/1251260/move-subfolders-up-one-level